# Json to display as HTML text - not original format

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I'm currently attempting to convert the json data I have to display as html text in my page, however when it does appear it is in json format. Therefore, I would like to know whether it is possible to eliminate all brackets etc & have plane html paragraphs.

```
require(["dojo"], function (dojo){

dojo.ready(function(){
// Look up the node we'll stick the text under.
var targetNode = dojo.byId("licenseContainer");  


// The parameters to pass to xhrGet, the url, how to handle it, and the callbacks.
var xhrArgs = {
url: "",
handleAs: "text",
timeout : 2000,

load: function(data){
  // Replace newlines with nice HTML tags.
  data = data.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");

  // Replace tabs with spaces.
  data = data.replace(/\t/g, "&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;");

  targetNode.innerHTML = data;
},
error: function(error){
  targetNode.innerHTML = "An unexpected error occurred: " + error;
}
}

 // Call the asynchronous xhrGet
 var deferred = dojo.xhrGet(xhrArgs);
});

});
```

At the moment the json appears like this on my page:

```
[{"Relevance":"Low","Name":"Clinton","id":1,,"Paragraph":Appointed secretary of state at the start of Mr Obama's first term, in January 2009, Mrs Clinton's health has been under intense scrutiny because she is considered a strong candidate for the Democratic nomination for president should she decide to run in 2016.}]
```

Am I able to filter or specify just the data in the "paragraph" just to display in html?

Any advice or help would be great!

Comment: Use data["paragraph"] .. like!

Comment: thank you for the reply, but I do not understand what you're trying to say

Comment: If you want to show paragraph from json then you can specify data["paragraph"] .. like this..

Comment: oh right. But, when I implement ' data = data.["Paragraph"];' my json no longer displays. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the handleAs property to 'text' which means your response is going to be just plain text. This will make it difficult to parse out the specific information you want from the response. Change the handleAs to json so that the information you retrieve from the server is then converted to a javascript object.

```
handleAs:'json'
```

At that point, you can call data['Paragraph'] or data.Paragraph. The same would apply if you wanted to get the value for your other key/value pairs. If you wanted Relevance, you would simply call

```
alert(data.Relevance);
```

EDIT:
Another thing, your json looks like it is not formatted properly which will cause errors if you have handleAs:'json'. It should look like this

```
{"Relevance":"Low","Name":"Clinton","id":1,"Paragraph":"Appointed secretary of state at the start of Mr Obama's first term, in January 2009, Mrs Clinton's health has been under intense scrutiny because she is considered a strong candidate for the Democratic nomination for president should she decide to run in 2016."}
```

Comment: Hi, I've been trying to put handleAs: 'json', but I keep getting an error that I can't figure out when I put 'json instead of text ' An unexpected error occurred: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function' any ideas why?

Comment: So after it makes the asynchronous call, it's calling your error handler right? If that's the case, your json may not be formatted properly. Judging by your example json, the data within the paragraph should be in quotes. It should be "Paragraph":"Appointed secretary of state at the start of Mr Obama's first term, in January 2009, Mrs Clinton's health has been under intense scrutiny because she is considered a strong candidate for the Democratic nomination for president should she decide to run in 2016."

You also have two commas in a row. It should look like this:

Comment: Its a random url example, that's why probably you can't access it :). Yes its calling my error handler, I've tested & looked at my json - no errors. So its not my json .. is it that I may need to require something else? Or does my script tag need to declare a type?

Comment: Yes, my json data is formatted properly I put it through http://jsonlint.com/ to make sure. I still have the same error.

Comment: Check this jsbin link out. http://jsbin.com/otepeq/3/  The first alert is with the JSON changes I proposed with removing the extra comma, adding quotes around Paragraph value, and removing brackets. The second is part is the JSON you provided. You'll notice it gets an undefined error when I try to parse it from string to JSON using the dojo JSON parser.

Comment: Would you know why the brackets would have this negative affect, isn't this part of the json format?